# How to use your own Monad in servant-websocket's conduit endpoint?

Tags: haskell, websocket, servant

I'm trying to figure out how to use a custom monad in the `ConduitT` definition of the `WebSocketConduit` endpoint provided by the `servant-websocket` library.

Say that I have this API:

```hs
type MyAPI = "ws" :> WebSocketConduit Value Value
```

if I try to define a handler for that endpoint that just copies input but I specify a Monad different from the parametric `m`:

```hs
ws :: ConduitT Value Value (Reader String) ()
ws _ = CL.map id
```

I get this error:

```
    • Couldn't match type: transformers-0.5.6.2:Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
                             String Data.Functor.Identity.Identity
                     with: resourcet-1.2.5:Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT
                             IO
```

I faced this problem because the monad I want to use is one created with Polysemy with lots of effects, but I wanted to keep the example simple using the Reader monad.

So the general question is, how do you use a custom monad in a Conduit Websocket endpoint?

**Solution**

Thanks to the tips from [fghibellini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3343425/fghibellini) this is the full solution to a toy example:

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{-
 stack --resolver lts-19.07 script --package servant --package servant-server
       --package servant-websockets --package polysemy --package aeson --package mtl
       --package wai --package warp --package conduit
-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Main where

import Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL
import Control.Monad.Except (ExceptT(ExceptT))
import Data.Aeson (ToJSON, FromJSON)
import Data.Char (toUpper)
import Data.Function ((&))
import GHC.Generics ( Generic )
import Network.Wai (Application)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Polysemy ( runM, Sem, Members, Embed )
import Polysemy.Error ( runError, Error )
import Polysemy.Trace ( trace, traceToStdout, Trace )
import Servant
import Servant.API.WebSocketConduit (WebSocketConduit)
import Servant.Server

-- Dummy message
newtype Message = Message { content :: String } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON Message
instance FromJSON Message

type MyApi = "toupper" :> ReqBody '[JSON] Message :> Post '[JSON] Message
            :<|> "ws-toupper" :> WebSocketConduit Message Message
            :<|> "ws-toupper-sem" :> WebSocketConduit Message Message


server :: Members '[Trace, Embed IO] r => ServerT MyApi (Sem r)
server = toupper :<|> wstoupper :<|> wstoupperWithSem

toupper :: Members '[Trace, Embed IO] r => Message -> Sem r Message
toupper (Message msg) = do
  trace $ "Received msg in the REST endpoint: " ++ msg
  return (Message . map toUpper $ msg)

wstoupper :: Monad m => ConduitT Message Message m ()
wstoupper = CL.map (\(Message msg) -> Message . map toUpper $ msg)

wstoupperWithSem :: ConduitT Message Message (ResourceT IO) ()
wstoupperWithSem = transPipe (liftIO . interpreter) semConduit
  where
    interpreter :: Sem '[Trace , Embed IO] a -> IO a
    interpreter sem = sem
      & traceToStdout
      & runM

    semConduit :: Members '[Trace, Embed IO] r => ConduitT Message Message (Sem r) ()
    semConduit = mapMC effect

    effect :: Members '[Trace] r => Message -> Sem r Message
    effect (Message msg) = do
      trace $ "Received msg through the WS: " ++ msg
      return (Message . map toUpper $ msg)

liftServer :: ServerT MyApi Handler
liftServer = hoistServer api interpreter server
  where
    interpreter :: Sem '[Trace, Error ServerError , Embed IO] a -> Handler a
    interpreter sem = sem
      & traceToStdout
      & runError
      & runM
      & liftHandler

    liftHandler = Handler . ExceptT


api :: Proxy MyApi
api = Proxy

app :: Application
app = serve api liftServer


main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Starting server on http://localhost:8080"
  run 8080 app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HasServer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-websockets-1.0.0/candidate/docs/Servant-API-WebSocketConduit.html#t:WebSocketConduit) instance of `WebSocketConduit` starts with:

```
instance (FromJSON i, ToJSON o) => HasServer (WebSocketConduit i o) ctx where

  type ServerT (WebSocketConduit i o) m = Conduit i (ResourceT IO) o
```

*link to [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-websockets-1.0.0/candidate/docs/src/Servant-API-WebSocketConduit.html#line-56)*

as you can see the monad is fixed to `ResourceT IO`. That's why your example won't compile.

You can ignore the `ResourceT` part as you can trivially lift an `IO` into it. So your task boils down to evaluating your monad stack until you get a simple `IO` operation.

To evaluate the `ReaderT String` layer in your example we would use
[`runReaderC :: Monad m => r -> ConduitT i o (ReaderT r m) res -> ConduitT i o m res`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.4.2/docs/Data-Conduit-Lift.html#v:runReaderC). But generally you'd use whatever "runs/evaluates" your Monad into `IO`.

The following code compiles fine:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Servant
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Aeson (Value)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL
import Servant.API.WebSocketConduit
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.Conduit.Lift (runReaderC)


type WebSocketApi = "echo" :> WebSocketConduit Value Value

server :: Server WebSocketApi
server = transPipe lift $ runReaderC "your-reader-state" echo
 where
  echo :: Conduit Value (ReaderT String IO) Value
  echo = CL.map id
```

there's a warning about using monad transformeres with conduit under [transPipe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.4.2/docs/Data-Conduit.html#v:transPipe), which you probably better read.

**Correction**

I just realized you used `Reader String` and not `ReaderT String IO`. I'm gonna leave the answer as it is as it illustrates a more common scenario, but for `Reader String` you'd just replace `lift` with `(pure . runIdentity)` to rewrap from `Identity` to `IO`.

Comment: Thanks @fghibellini !! You put me in the in the right track. Could you just double check the solution I posted in the question body? I'm still unease about having two different configuration paths one using `hoistserver` and all the servant machinery and another completely different just constructing Conduit pipes.

Comment: If I understand correctly you'd prefer to have the hoistServer taking care of the monad used within counduit as well. I think this will not be possible with the current definition of `WebSocketConduit` as it doesn't really seem to account for hoisting e.g. notice how the `m` parameter in `ServerT` is completely ignored. But I might be wrong, I'm not super familiar with any of this.

Comment: Yeah. I'm implementing the ticketing pattern to authenticate the websocket. So both the endpoint and the ws need to access the same cache, ie. use same monad. Thanks anyway, I can just "duplicate" initialization code for both servers and that solves the problem.